# How to fix headphone audio after ubuntu update?

Tags: 16.04, audio-jack

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y400 and I recently updated to 16.04, and now the laptop speakers will play sound, but the headphone jack will not.

How could I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my audio was muted. I ran alsamixer from the terminal, and unmuted the headphone channel by hitting m.